# Java listeners method parameters

Tags: java, android

I am writing this code for an Android game project:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button b1 = null;
    Button b2 = null;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        b1 = new Button(this);
        b2 = new Button(this);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // how parameter "v" got its value.,
        // and where it was initialized???
    }
}
```

I noticed the `onClick(View v)` method of onClickListener,
and wanted to ask where is the parameter "View v" initialized?
I know it holds the reference for the clicked view, but where and 
how does it get its value?

Same question regarding this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // where/how it initialized "e" ??
}
```

Comment: "View v" not initialized, it's a call back method for OS. it pass the argument only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever user touches the screen, Android has its own handlers/buffers to process the cordinates (x and y) and dectects view. Each view has its own window token registered with WindowManager and it process the call back to the onClick(view v);

Answer (score 5):

Both `onClick` and `actionPerformed` are callback methods, which means they are called by the Android OS, which passes them their arguments.

Comment: yeah a callback., just wondering where they got their values like...
anyway thanks for mentioning "they are called by the android os"
:)

Comment: @tuty_fruity The Android OS takes care of the values. It has access to the relevant instances, such as the View passed to onClick, and knows which instances to pass to the callback methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look in the code:

See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#3436 how a `View` object is created

Because `Button` is a subclass of `View` you create the `View v` parameter by instanziating Button with `Button b1 = new Button(this);`

When you call `setOnClickListener` you register a callback method (on View object) which should be executed. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#4379

The real click is performed in the method `performClick()`. This method reads your registered onclick(View v) from the onclick listener method and executes it.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#4432

You can also have a look for the Observer pattern.